# Are there any hidden classes? (no blue exclamation mark)

Tags: bravely-default

Basically, are there any classes that can't be found by following the blue exclamation mark? If so, what/where/when are they!

Answer (score 1):

No, all classes are unlockable by following the side quest indicator (blue exclamation mark).
Some are much later in the game than others.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the battle for the Pirate job didn't have a marker at the boss's location. The ship doesn't even have a pin on the over world map either!